# How to create the Data Source property of the ConnectionString in ASP/net MVC?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I can't find a decent tutorial/blog that has a solution for my problem.

On my laptop I run a Microsoft SQLServer named 'SQLSERVER'. There's a database in it called 'SalesDB'. I can't figure out how to fill in the Data Source property of the ConnectionString in the web.config file in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application to get my application connected with the database.

This is the default connectionstring:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Labo7SQL-20131226161445;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Labo7SQL-20131226161445.mdf" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) tends to be a pretty useful resource for formatting a connection string.  For MS SQL Server, [you have a few options](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).  Such as:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

or

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

or

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Using the last one as an example, yours might be something like:

```
Server=localhost\SQLSERVER;Database=SalesDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Data Source` value should be the name (or ip address) of your sql sever. The `Initial Catalog` value should be the name of your database...`SalesDB` and you should remove the `AttachDBFilename`